# ListView OnFocusChangeListener

Tags: android, android-listview, focus

I have a ListView in a ListFragment and I want to change the background of the fragment when the user changes the focused item in the list.  I specifically say focus here because this is a Google TV app so I'm targeting dpad controls and item selection does something else.

The questions is, how can I get a notification or callback when the list item focus changes, similar on onListItemClick, but for focus?  I've tried setting the OnFocusChangeListener on the row view when the adapter creates it but that doesn't ever seem to be called.

Comment: If you got the answer then please post it

Answer (score 0):

Use `onItemSelected` instead, this will be invoked when an item in listView has been selected.

```
listview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        //do stuff here       
    }
});
```

Selected state should be used when user navigate a listview with a directional control (such as when navigating through a list with a d-pad). In this situation, the listView will get focused state and the listItems inside it will get selected state. For more information about state, see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)